# Extend $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{i}{2} ,\frac{-1}{2},\frac{-i}{2} )$ to an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products, orthonormal

Consider $\mathbb{C}^4$ with the standard inner-product$ < , >$. Extend $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{i}{2} ,\frac{-1}{2},\frac{-i}{2} )$ to an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^4$.

How is this possible with one vector? Would we just find 3 orthogonal vectors to this one and then divide each by the norm of itself? Can we use the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: Add to any basis and use Gram-Schmidt process

Comment: @Gregory: Your strategy sounds good, because it's fairly easy to write down three mutually-orthogonal vectors that are also orthogonal to that particular unit vector. :) (Just be sure to use the _Hermitian_ inner product, which entails complex conjugation of one vector.)